# aws lambda function querying data base time out

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda

Trying to connect to PostgreSQL database with Lambda function both of which resides in AWS, but it doesn't seem like the connection can be established; Here is a snippet of my node(6.10) function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var pg = require("pg");
    const connectionStr = "pg://user:pwd@host:5432/dbname";
    pg.connect(connectionStr, function(err, client){
        if(err) {
            console.log("A connection error occurred");
        } else {
            console.log("Connection established");
            var query = client.query("select * from makes", function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("An error occurred");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Succeed");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            query.on("end", function(){
                console.log("Close");
            })
       }     
   })
};
```

A few things I've tried:

1) Tested on local machine, works fine;

2) Already set up the VPC and subnets of the lambda function which is the same as shown on my data base instance dashboard;

3) Tried to increase the time out to 20 seconds and 1 minute, still time out;

4) Checked the log file, which shows only this, note no message shows either the connection failed or succeeded:

> 2017-06-15T01:06:26.173Z ce971015-5166-11e7-b733-0fe749dc9c4a Task
>   timed out after 20.00 seconds

What could be the problem? Anybody has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database's security group needs to allow access from the Lambda-associated security group.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the reply. Sounds like what I've missed. Do you have any reference on how to do that?

Comment: [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)

Comment: And you never release the connection, which will result in immediate connection leak, and your code will freeze. If you want to avoid messing with connections, use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) instead.

Comment: @vitaly-t Hi, thanks for the reply. I am trying to use the `pg-promise` module; But the lambda still times out, I can see the connection log file in postgresql events, which means the connection should have been established. How do I release the connection using pg-promise? I tried the `db.query.then.catch` pattern. Does this release the connection? Sorry still new to javascript.

Comment: @Psidom You do not need to release the connection in `pg-promise`, it is automatic. The issue must be elsewhere, as per the first comment, perhaps.